# Request in Http/2.0 gets a response in Http/1.1

Tags: http

I'm playing around with `Http/2.0` at the moment. I noticed an unexpected behaviour when I send a request (`Http/2.0`) to a server which **supports** `Http/2.0`. The response which I get back was in `Http/1.1`.

Why is that? Did I missunderstand something?

Comment: need more info about your server configuration

Comment: It's not my server. Just any server which is configured to allow Http/2.0 (such as [akamai](https://http2.akamai.com/) is)